# using ex with perl support

Tags: ex-command

I've just learnt how to run perl commands within vi, but I had to install vim.gtk in order to have perl support.     But I want to incorporate these perl commands into bash scripts that call ex.  Is there a version of ex that has perl support?

Thanks!

Comment: What distribution are you using? Debian/Ubuntu?

Comment: If your `ex` is provided by Vim, it should have Perl support. On Arch Linux, `ex` is provided by `vi` (that's the BSD `vi`), so it has no support for anything. Worst case, you can always do `vim -Nes` to use `vim` as `ex`.

Comment: Using debian 14.04.

Comment: I have two vims, the regular one, which has no perl support and vim.gtk which does.    vim.gtk -Nes filename << EOF etc works just like ex filename << EOF.     However, when I type a perl command at the question mark prompt, I don't get the same response as when I'm inside of vim.gtk.    For example the first perl command I want to write is :perl $a{'{'}=1.      When I type this at the question mark prompt, with or without the :, I crash out with the error   a: undefined variable.    When I type it from within vim.gtk, the command works fine.    Could you please advise?     Thanks